# Two Versions of Python in Homebrew

Tags: xcode, homebrew, python

Doing `brew upgrade` tells me that Python failed due to an issue with Xcode and I should `brew install --build-from-source python@3.10` but then another `upgrade` to catch whatever depends on Python demands that I "upgrade" Python with `brew install --build-from-source python@3.9` .

**Will that mean I have two versions of python installed?**  (Actually three, since Apple bundles another one in a different path)  **Will that be a problem with other things?**

Answer (score 1):

You can install python using the `@3.x` syntax without issue. They will be installed "keg-only" which means that they are not added to your `$PATH`.

Your `$PATH` is a list of folders to search when you try to run a program. If a program is not added to your `$PATH`, then it means it's just another folder on your computer and won't impact anything that doesn't look for it specifically.

You can have as many parallel installations so long as they aren't added to your `$PATH` and brew understands this. It gives instructions for linking it to your `$PATH` manually if you need it to be automatically selected.

---

It seems like you already have `python@3.9` and `python@3.10` installed anyways.